# Execute PHP code without getting redirected to a different page

Tags: php, html, datepicker, action, forms

So I have been busy working on this reservation system for school. I've been trying to make this date input field.

When a customer wants to reserve a product, he/she has to enter the date to let us know how long he/she wants to have the product. It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot system]

By pressing 'Data invoeren' I do not want another page getting loaded, I want the two dates put into a PHP variable so I can give the customer the feedback of having received the correct dates. You can see this at the bottom: "U reserveert het product X dagen." (English: You will reserve the product for X days). I want X to be the number of days.

The data input field looks like this in HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="../app/src/dateValidation.php">
        <p>Van:<input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate"> </p>
        <p>Tot: <input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate"> </p>
        <button type="submit">Data invoeren</button>
</form>
```

By pressing the button, it now redirects to that PHP file and executes the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// Functies maken

    // Submitting user input into variables.
    $fromDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fromDate']);
    $toDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['toDate']);

    if ($fromDate = "" || $toDate = "") {

        echo "Geen datum geselecteerd";
        exit();

    } else {

        // Amount of days that the product will be reserved
        $fromTimeStamp = strtotime($fromDate);
        $toTimeStamp = strtotime($toDate);

        $finalStamp = $toTimeStamp - $fromTimeStamp;

    }


}
```

But how do I make this code run without getting redirected?

Many thanks in advance,

Frank.

Comment: Have a search around the acronym `AJAX`.

Comment: *"I do not want another page getting loaded"* - Right, Google that. You'll get a lot of hits.

Comment: You should use ```AJAX``` to send your form data to your PHP file "in the background"

Comment: Do you really need it to be PHP? It would be way easier to do in JavaScript (jQuery to be exact). I say that because your PHP code does not seem to do anything really important that requiers going to the server, everything can be done on the client side.

Comment: Agreed with @MichałSkrzypek - I don't believe there's even a need for AJAX, simply do the calculations / display client-side in javascript / jQuery.

Comment: @MichałSkrzypek I plan to post this to the database later on when a customer places the reservation. Therefore I would like to work with solely PHP. I'm going to have a look into AJAX. Thanks for the input.

Comment: AJAX is based on JavaScript anyway. If I understand correctly, you should use JS as I said before and just make an AJAX call when you actually want to save data input, not calculate it. The best way would be to calculate it (in JS), display to the user and if they still want to save it (so when they like the offer) then you should make the AJAX call.